# QuickDialog login form being the first loading controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, quickdialog

I recently started iOS development, and had an objective to create a login view. I encountered QuickDialog which I think will do the job. In their example, they provide the following code:

```
QRootElement *root = [[QRootElement alloc] init];
root.title = @"Hello World";
root.grouped = YES;
QSection *section = [[QSection alloc] init];
QLabelElement *label = [[QLabelElement alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" Value:@"world!"];

[root addSection:section];
[section addElement:label];

UINavigationController *navigation = [QuickDialogController controllerWithNavigationForRoot:root];
[self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];
```

It looks like the code creates a specialised controller that will load up the custom view. I was not sure where to add this snippet of code, so I added it on my viewDidLoad for the original launching view in the storyboard. However, the view in the storyboard is shown for a split second before the view created by the QuickDialog is presented.

I was wondering, how can I modify the app so that the controller obtained by the QuickDialogController loads its view at app launch. I am hoping to create a login form using QuickDialog. Would this Login view appear somewhere in storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Just to tie this one off, here's a complete example of using QuickDialog in the storyboard by inheriting from QuickDialogController:

```
// MyController.h
@interface MyController : QuickDialogController
@end


// MyController.m
#import "MyController.h"

@interface MyController ()
@end

@implementation MyController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.root = [[QRootElement alloc] init];
    self.root.title = @"Hello World";
    self.root.grouped = YES;
    QSection *section = [[QSection alloc] init];
    QLabelElement *label = [[QLabelElement alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" Value:@"world!"];

    [self.root addSection:section];
    [section addElement:label];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Comment: this seems to work great, but the problem is the `self.root.grouped` = YES doesn't seem to work. It doesn't make it grouped.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the grouped option when storyboard is creating the controller in initWithCoder, which means you have to create the QRootElement there:

1. Add in your MyController class implementation the following code:

   ```
   -(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
       if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
           QRootElement *_root = [[QRootElement alloc] init];
           _root.grouped = YES;
           self.root = _root;
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```
2. Then continue to customize the list of elements in the viewDidLoad referencing the self.root

Answer (score 1):

So everything works but you don't want to show the animation of the quickdialog login form appearing? Try setting `animated:NO` on the last line.

QuickDialog was not designed to really be used from Storyboard, although you can do so, by creating a controller that inherits from QuickDialogController.

Comment: That could probably work, but it seems that work is done loading the first navigation controller, which may not be ideal. I did find the solution, I will post it here later on today. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Eduardo, can you add a more complete snippet like Benjamin did, but that properly shows up as Grouped?